# pointer in array of pointer print value without *

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
 char arr[3][10];
 char *ptr[3];
 strcpy(arr[1],"abcde");
 ptr[1]=arr[1];
 printf("%s\n",arr[1]);
 printf("%p\n", &arr[1]);
 printf("%p\n", ptr[1]);
 printf("%p\n", &ptr[1]);
 printf("%s\n",ptr[1]);
 printf("%s\n", *(ptr+1));
 return 0;
}
```

Result

```
abcde
0x7ffdcbbd8daa
0x7ffdcbbd8daa
0x7ffc30ed1188
abcde
abcde
```

I know `ptr` is an array of pointer. Dereferencing a pointer needs a unary operator before it. Why can we dereference the pointer `ptr[1]` without the  `*`? Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your problem and your question? Do you mean the (wrongly typed) line `printf("%s\n") ptr[1]);`? (In the future, ***copy-paste*** code instead of rewriting it into the question.)

Comment: Also note that `arr[1]` and `&arr[1]` might be pointing to the same location, but sematically they are different. `arr[1]` is equal to `&arr[1][0]` which is of type `char *`. `&arr[1]` is of type `char (*)[10]`.

Comment: You are not dereferencing, printf() takes a pointer to string for "%s". You are giving pointer in ptr[1].

Comment: "*Why can we dereference the pointer `ptr[1]` without the \**" where you think this is done?

Answer (score 1):

`%s` specifier in printf expects and argument of type `char *` (it should point to a null terminated string). `ptr[1]` is of `char *` type. So, no need to apply dereference operator here.

Answer (score 0):

You got it wrong. Here:

```
printf("%s\n", ptr[1]);
```

- The format `%s` expects a pointer to `char`.
- `ptr[1]` is a `char` pointer.

> why I use *(ptr+1) it prints the same value?

Because this will apply pointer arithmetics, which involve `ptr`, add 1 to it (by one here we mean the size of an `int`), and then use the `*` operator and refer to the content of this memory address (where it points) to, which is the same value as `ptr[1]`.

---

`arr[1]` and `&arr[1]` might be pointing to the same location, but sematically they are different. `arr[1]` is equal to `&arr[1][0]` which is of type `char*`. `&arr[1]` is of type `char (*)[10]`, as Some programmer dude said.

Comment: so why i use *(ptr+1) it prints the same value

Comment: "you are not dereferencing." --> With `ptr[1]` looks like code _is_ de-referencing `ptr` at offset 1.  Of course that results in a `char *`, which does not need another de-reference operation for printing with `"%s"`.

Comment: Because the end up at the same value @QuocAnhPham, check my updated answer, hope that helps! BTW, you have two helpful answers, consider *accepting* one by clicking on the Tick Mark on the left of an answer.